# Loading dots in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, css, qualtrics

trying to add a in-betweener screen that just has the loading dots animation in Qualtrics. I'm not sure how to add CSS code to one question only. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can add CSS to a question by adding a style tag to the question text in HTML view (the styles will apply to all questions on the page):

```
Your question text here.
<style>
/* CSS */
</style>
```

If you need more granularity, you can modify the styles of individual elements using JavaScript.